# Code linting for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, static-analysis

Are there any code linting tools for ObjectiveC?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at the [**LLVM/Clang Static Analyzer**](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-static-analyzer-diagnostics)

The LLVM/Clang static analyzer is a standalone tool that find bugs in C and Objective-C programs and it is very early in development.

A static analyzer based on **clang**. The goal of the Clang project is to create a new C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ front-end for the LLVM compiler.

### Edit

Clang has now been integrated into Xcode and can easily be run as a menu option "Build & Analyse"

[image]

Comment: The above link is 404'ed, for finding information about Clang / LLVM static analysis, I recommend reading [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-static-analyzer-diagnostics)

and then `jmp` to [this](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 6):

It's worth mentioning [OCLint](http://oclint.org/) too. It covers some things not touched by the Clang analyser, such as:

- Complicated code - high cyclomatic complexity and NPath complexity
- Code smells - long method, long parameter list, redundant code

Check out the [home page](http://oclint.org/) for more details.

Comment: is there any tutorials for OCLint? I can't find anything better than oclint --help.

Answer (score 5):

I know it is an old question, but I will add another one static analysis tool here for the sake of completeness,  **Infer, from Facebook**

You can see their [home page](http://fbinfer.com/), works with iOS and Android projects, and spare Obj-C/Java/C files

Answer (score 2):

There is also the commercial tool [FauxPas](http://fauxpasapp.com), which catches a lot of code smells, but also stuff like unused graphics, translation format argument mismatch, etc.

It’s not super cheap, but I‘m a happy user. There's a time-limited trial version available, which is fully functional, as far as I know.

Comment: Is it OK to link to commercial tools? I’ve omitted the link both because I’m on mobile and because I’m not sure.

Comment: Generally, yes.

Answer (score 2):

For simple syntax stuff like enforcing number of line breaks, sorting imports, etc., also have a look at [Clang Format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). The easiest way to install is probably via [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/clang-format).