# Lint for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, lint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code linting for Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563225/code-linting-for-objective-c)

Is there any lint tool for Objective-c?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Xcode includes the Clang static analyzer, labeled as `Build and Analyze` (simply `Analyze` under Xcode 4).
http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html

**Edit:**

OCLint, based on Clang, provides additional checks of code style and complexity.
http://oclint.org

Comment: http://oclint.org is broken :(

Comment: It was working up until xCode 13.4, and oclint is not supporting xCode 14 ATM :(