# Lint-checking tools for Objective-C development

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, static-analysis, lint

Large projects with multiple developers often result in code that is inconsistent in style. I am looking for a [lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software))-like tool tailored to Objective-C that goes beyond the scope of the Clang [Static Analyser](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) and checks for adherence to *stylistic* conventions; e.g. braces, indentation, comment formatting, declaring variables at the top of functions and so on.

I am aware of [AnalysisTool](http://www.karppinen.fi/analysistool/), but it doesn't quite do what I'm after. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926842/lint-for-objective-c) question asked elsewhere on SO, but it's not clear whether the question-asker was after the same thing.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: PLease update the link of your `Analysis Tool`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently stumbled across [`uncrustify`](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/), which has support for Objective-C. It appears well-written and adding additional checks (and respective fixes) seems straight-forward.

It's not all-in-one, but in combination with the static analyser and a good differencing tool, it should do the job.

Comment: I thought uncrustify was a formatting tool.  How does it check style issues (other than formatting)?

Comment: @BrianLiang: I was answering my own question. It was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: I think you should edit your question then.. because it's unclear that your looking for a tool to help you format vs a tool that check that formatting is correct...

Answer (score 9):

I was doing the same research and I just found [OCLint](http://oclint.org/)