# Does Objective-C have similar tool like StyleCop for .net?

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions

I had been used StyleCop/FxCop for years with my original team members for .net development, and found they are really useful. Now I join a new team for iOS development. The team members are all very junior and don't have much sense of high quality code. I wonder if there is any tool that I can use in build phases, to force the team follow name conventions etc. 
Thanks!
-Elfe

Comment: That is a great question - I am spending sooo much time reviewing and fixing my team's code - hence I totally am with you on that.

Comment: If I knew of such a tool, I'd be beating it down people's throats. Best I can suggest is the LLVM Static Analyzer, but that'll just find mistakes and not code style silliness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of [OCLint](http://oclint.org/) and [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) might be sufficient, depending on your standards for quality code. Found a similar question on this post: [Lint-checking tools for Objective-C development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011416/lint-checking-tools-for-objective-c-development)

Comment: Thank you very much. Just took a quick look at them, and found uncrustify is mainly for formatting (yeah, it's very useful!). For OCLint, seems to me their are not many rules it provides http://oclint.org/rules/ . Can I found more rules? (One most useful rule is check spelling of class/function/variable names and also the up/lower cases.)

Comment: Unfortunately not, except the standard LLVM Static Analyzer that's included in Xcode. There's a command-line tool for it too. It seems to do plenty of checks: rules here http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html. Both OCLint and Clang are open source, you could add rules yourself.